# WWF Workflow persistence store exception

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, sqlworkflowpersistencese

We have a system that is using "WWF" as its workflow engine and the requests to proceed with the workflow faild frequently and the log is filled with this exception.

**System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceException**: The SqlWorkflowInstanceStore lock does not exist in the database. This could have occurred because the SQL Server is busy or because the connection was temporarily lost.

and it fires in this `event (application.Aborted = (e) =>{})`, Any ideas about how to solve this issue ?

Here is how I load the workflow and relase the lock

```
            //Create an instance of the workflow and its application and associate with workflow application.
            Activity workflow = Activator.CreateInstance(workflowType) as Activity;
            WorkflowApplication application = new WorkflowApplication(workflow);
            application.SynchronizationContext = SyncSynchronizationContext.SingletonInstance;

            //Hold the workflow store            
            application.InstanceStore = CreateInstanceStore(WorkflowDatabaseConnectionString);
            var instanceHandle = application.InstanceStore.CreateInstanceHandle(guid);
            var ownerCommand = new CreateWorkflowOwnerCommand();
            var view = application.InstanceStore.Execute(instanceHandle, ownerCommand, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

            application.InstanceStore.DefaultInstanceOwner = view.InstanceOwner;
            // Do whatever needs to be dome with multiple WorkflowApplications

            if (pParticipant != null)
                application.Extensions.Add(pParticipant);

            //Register workflow application services from the external world
            ExternalRegisteredServices.ForEach(service => application.Extensions.Add(service));

            ReadOnlyCollection<BookmarkInfo> currentBookmarks = null;
            Dictionary<string, object> wfContextBag = null;

            application.PersistableIdle = (workflowApplicationIdleEventArgs) =>
            {
                currentBookmarks = workflowApplicationIdleEventArgs.Bookmarks;

                wfContextBag = workflowApplicationIdleEventArgs
                    .GetInstanceExtensions<WorkflowContext>()
                    .First()
                    .GetBag();
                return PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
            };

            application.OnUnhandledException = (e) =>
            {
                if (wfUnhandledExceptionEventHandler != null)
                    wfUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(e);
                return UnhandledExceptionAction.Abort;
            };

            application.Aborted = (e) =>
            {
                if (wfAbortedEventHandler != null)
                    wfAbortedEventHandler(e);
            };

            application.Completed = (e) =>
            {
                if (wfCompletedEventHandler != null)
                    wfCompletedEventHandler(e);
            };

            application.Load(guid);

            BookmarkResumptionResult resumptionResult = BookmarkResumptionResult.NotFound;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bookmarkName))
                resumptionResult = application.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, null);

            if (resumptionResult != BookmarkResumptionResult.Success)
                currentBookmarks = application.GetBookmarks();

            var deleteOwnerCommand = new DeleteWorkflowOwnerCommand();
            application.InstanceStore.Execute(instanceHandle, deleteOwnerCommand, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            instanceHandle.Free();
```

Comment: Did you configure the database?

Comment: Yes I believe so, but when I comment the last 3 lines no exception is thrown !!

Comment: Maybe you don't have to delete the workflow owner? Have you checked to make sure you do?

Comment: Yes I did and it solved the problem, but I believe that you have to delete the ownership or release the lock once you have finished using the instance, Right ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  You might be correct, but I've never had to do that.  Again, I'd run through the process once and check the database to see if there is a lock.

Comment: How would I do that check ?

Comment: Well, start with a clean database.  Run a workflow in your normal manner to completion.  Don't delete/release, just let the workflow complete.  Now check the database again.  Is there an instance in storage?  Does it have an owner?  Is there a lock?  If not, you don't have to.  If there is, then you need to.  Again, I've never done that, so I have no idea how to do it or if it even needs to be done.  Never got far enough to have it crop up as an issue :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using application.Unload(), this will help you to solve your Abort exception. By default, the unload operation must complete in 30 seconds. However, if it doesn't happens then Abort event gets triggered.